# Is it possible to run a launch agent as a user with sudo permissions?

Tags: macos, permissions, sudo, launchd, daemon

I have an executable that needs to run every time a user logs in. It needs to run in the context of that user, but with root permissions, as if the user had run it with `sudo`.

I have looked through Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) as well as the website [launchd.info](http://launchd.info/) for a way to do this, but haven't been able to find anything.

If I create a Launch Agent (in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` or `/Library/LaunchAgents`), or a Launch Daemon with the `UserName` property set, it runs as the user (as desired), but I cannot do anything that requires elevated privileges.

If I create a Launch Daemon (in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`) it runs as root (with the desired privileges), but without any user context. If I use `su <username> -c "<command>"` or `sudo -u <username> <command>` from the Launch Daemon, I can then run a command as the user, but it runs without sudo privileges.

Is there a way to run a launch agent with sudo permissions?

Comment: a few suggestions:  this .plist generator suggests that you can specify the username.  You could try `<key>UserName</key>
 <string>root</string>` (I haven't).  Alternatively, you could run as `root` from within the script, as suggested in various ways here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-sudo-command-inside-a-script

Answer (score 0):

I'm no guru, so I don't know if this is bad advice. I'm sure I'll get killed with negatives if it is, but here goes:

If you insert a password into a user's keychain, you can access and use it in a script.

Extract the password (stored here as 'scriptsudo' in USER's keychain):

```
PASS=$(security find-generic-password -l "scriptsudo" -a USER -w | tr -d '\n')
```

Using the password for a 'chown' command in a script:

```
rslt=$(echo "$PASS" | sudo -S chown -R :GR-Access /Users/XXX/folder 2>&1)
```

-S option for sudo tells it to get the password from sysin. The echo command makes it available to sudo. In this example, the output from the sudo command is stored in 'rslt'. This is not required, I did it so I could log the result.

The script can be run from launchd using the usual plist method.

To split 'rslt' into array see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201229/8245469 (Wrong Answer #7)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).